# For any natural number greater than or equal to 2 and x is any real number, show that $n(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}kx^{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I recognize that the left-hand side of the equation is a derivative of $(1+x)^{n}$, but I don't know what to do with this information.

I feel like a combinatorial proof is what is most appropriate but I'm struggling to see how to start.

Comment: binomial theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution: $$\binom{n}{k} k x^{k-1} = \dfrac{n!\cdot k}{(n-k)!k!} \cdot x^{k-1} = \dfrac{(n-1)! \cdot n}{[(n-1) - (k-1)]! (k-1)!} \cdot x^{k-1} = n \binom{n-1}{k-1} x^{k-1}$$
Then we shall have $$n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1} x^{k-1} = n(1 + x)^{n-1}$$ according to the Binomial Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Using derivative is a good idea. Start from the binomial theorem

$$(1+x)^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{k}$$ and find derivative of each side. The result is immediate. Note that on the RHS you'll use the fact that a derivative of a sum is a sum of derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation that the expression is a derivative is the key to, I believe, the fastest solution. By the binomial theorem,
$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k
\implies \frac{d}{dx}(1+x)^n = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k
\implies \frac{d}{dx}(1+x)^n = \sum_{0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{d}{dx}x^k
\implies n(1+x)^{n - 1} = \sum_{0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}kx^{k -1}
$$
which is the required result.